# Typescript dynamic type depends on value (generic)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Is it possible get dynamic type depended on value of key `dataIndex` (create dynamic discriminating union type with generic)?

```js
type EntityList<EntityType> = {
  dataIndex: keyof EntityType;
  render?: (value: any /*bad*/, record: EntityType) => void;
}[]

// Some dynamic type
type Issue = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  description?: string;
  flag?: boolean;
};

const arr:EntityList<Issue> = [
  { dataIndex: 'id', render: (id, record) => { 
    console.log({id, record}); } // id should be number
  }, 

  { dataIndex: 'name', render: (name, record) => { 
    console.log({name, record}); } // name should be string
  }, 

  { dataIndex: 'flag', render: (flag, record) => { 
    console.log({flag, record}); } // flag should be boolean
   }, 
]
```

answer:

```js
type EntityList<EntityType> = {
  [K in keyof EntityType]: {
    dataIndex: K, 
    render?: (value: EntityType[K], record: EntityType) => void
  }
}[keyof EntityType][]
```

thanks @Tobias S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
type EntityList<EntityType> = {
  [K in keyof Issue]: {
    dataIndex: K, 
    render?: (value: Issue[K], record: EntityType) => void
  }
}[keyof Issue][]
```

We create a mapped type and iterate over all keys of `Issue`. Afterwards we convert this type to a union of all possible combinations with `[keyof Issue]`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDD0oAgZQewWwKYQCYE8B2BDOBLAxhAC6oAOCwxZEAkgM60CuSAvBAN7AQQ7IBcE6BnABGCAE4BuTgOwJ+tQmJzoA5lK7IEtPEpKEcMdAH55i5WukAzADaYVJiMJgxrCTOikBfKRVJIAouj6xAAyOAoAPIHBqAAqfgB8EKwcXADaANLc6BAA1gioMJY09EwAuvxsyJiEmNTomgAe-BkANBBiCA3iDgAUAG6Y1kz8dIwImWXtnXgwYnwQ0TjE8WQAlMlJ-TA8nsCeafmFxWPlaWUgs+gKEJhiYvxLoeGEEacISaxp0mwoNXXdZoQADkPGB0y6mgeEF6PAhs3mG2YSV+V1oLgQADprDAVL02HCOggEchPGsJBBPJT2uBuMgILQABYwBjWemiARCURiH5-Wr1Jr8YFYRDgondaG9EUIeFzZBIlEQNEY7G4-HS2XzMkUqmeGmQaUM5ms9lIBRKVS86r8wFCmx2MWdCX8Xr2lSa+WbdhKwzo1yqvFsN0e7WU6kQWluo0stmOJBODHuYBlIA)

This does not quite match your requirement since you wanted `flag` to be of type `boolean`. But since the `flag` property is optional the type is `boolean | undefined`. To fix this, add `-?`:

```
type EntityList<EntityType> = {
  [K in keyof Issue]-?: {
    dataIndex: K, 
    render?: (value: Issue[K], record: EntityType) => void
  }
}[keyof Issue][]
```